# Inline Voltage Divider - do they exist?

Tags: resistors, enclosure

I'm looking for a neat off the shelf solution to halving a voltage via a resistor network. Some kind of small module, (probably GND, signal in, signal out) that can be wired inline with a sensor that delivers 0-10V for feeding into a 0-5V ADC.
I do NOT want to make my own PCB, enclosure etc. This should be something that can be dropped straight into production equipment.

I have tried googling the title desription but nothing comes up. Do such devices exist, and if so what are they called?

---

Thanks for the replies - the term I am looking for is "precision attenuator"

Comment: Something like a LT317?

Comment: At risk of sounding like I've missed the point, what about a couple of resistors of the same value?

Comment: @richter This has to go into production equipment - it can't be a couple of resistors hanging on a bit of wire. It needs terminal connections at the very least and its own enclosure

Comment: Maybe an L-pad attenuator might fit your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"wired inline with a sensor"

What cabling are you using for the sensor? You can get inline attenuators like these:

[image]

http://ch.farnell.com/aim-cambridge-cinch-connectivity/27-9300-6/bnc-attenuator-male-female-6db/dp/2357852?mckv=s6zXSYADd_dc|pcrid|90940810960|kword||match||plid||slid||product|2357852|pgrid|18061213600|ptaid|pla-294680686006|&gross_price=true&CATCI=pla-294680686006&CAAGID=18061213600&CAGPSPN=pla&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIrtCovZni3AIVxuR3Ch09RQ1xEAQYASABEgJr3fD_BwE&CAWELAID=120185710000331336

Comment: Thanks - it would be something like that except I need a precision division eg 0.1% resistors or better

Comment: I'm sure if you look around you will find precision parts of the same type.

Comment: This looked pretty precise. 

https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/829/UBER_SUHNER_6906.01.A_dataSheet-1022483.pdf

Answer (score 7):

An image search for "glanded miniature terminal box" shows up the following products.

[image]

*Figure 1. Something like this should do the trick. You need three terminals for cable termination and resistive divider component termination.*

Comment: OP indicated they didn't want to make their own stuff...

Comment: These are ready-made. To attenuate something *has* to be added between the sensor and the production equipment. The OP's question is too vague to answer any better.

Comment: @richter OP said he didn't want to make his own PCB or enclosure. This is a ready made enclosure, and with 2 resistors its a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

A terminal input module will do this.  They are available in different voltage ratios.  A link to one manufacturer's product of this type:
https://s.campbellsci.com/documents/au/category-brochures/b_tims.pdf

The source website:
https://www.campbellsci.com.au/vdiv2-1